# Python script is not seen by ajax get call

Tags: ajax, python-3.x

I have something weird happening and cannot figure it out. So I need to call a python script after clicking a button. The ajax call is as follows (i don't need to pass any parameters to python):

```
function submitForm() {
    $.ajax({url: 'fodername/filename.py',
        success: function(rs){
            console.log(rs);
    }
})
```

I am getting 
jquery.js:9664 GET http://localhost/sitefolder/fodername/filename.py 404 (Not Found)

P.S. I am in Python 3 if it makes difference.

Many thanks!

Debugging so far:
1. If I change file url in ajax call to any other file in the same folder - it sucessfully returs the response

2. I tried url with local host (the same result)
3. Spelling double checked, copy-pasted, re-copy-pasted - nothing helps.

What else can I be missing? Looks like the problem is relative to this file specifically (never sent ajax calls to pythons before)

P.S: I am in Python 3 if it makes any difference

Thank you!

Comment: Which server a you using? apache, nginx, python simple http server or something else?

Comment: Stanislav, looks like none of the above. Unfortunately, I don't engineer the system. Do I need to dig into python http server?

Comment: If you have no server, no one to execute the script for you. If you try to get 'fodername/filename.py' from local drive, you'll get file content or error. Simplest way to execute python code on server is a CGI, see https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_cgi_programming.htm for examples.

Comment: Thank you! I will check it out now.